# Multiple actions ,one form and one textbox using javascript

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, servlets

I am having this form below which performs sometimes first action and sometimes last action instead of both the actions one after another continuously.

**Form:**

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script language="Javascript">
         function OnButton1()
         {
             document.Form1.action = "http://localhost:8084/WorldCupFinal/finalsearching1";
             document.Form1.target="_blank";
             document.Form1.submit();
             document.Form1.action = "http://localhost:8084/SemiFinal/finalsearching1";
             document.Form1.target="_blank";
             document.Form1.submit();

         }
        </script>
        <form name="Form1" method="post" target="_blank">
            File Name <input type="text" name="t1" size="10" ><br />
            <INPUT type="button" value="Button1"
                   name=name onclick="OnButton1();" >
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

finalsearching1 is java servlet program which takes input as filename searches for a file in some system depending on the action(in my local host as well as in other IP address).

But this action is only performed only one time by my servlet. I want 
to execute both actions one after another or is there any way that i can execute them concurrently which takes less time. This scenario is performed by me for 2 different buttons(2 actions). I want to perform it using a single button having single text box and multiple actions takes place.

I have searched a lot and i am finding it that this can be performed using AJAX or if possible using javascript.
Could you please provide me solution for it.

Thank you for your concern in advance.

Here is my finalsearching1 program code:

```
import static java.awt.SystemColor.window;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import static java.io.FileDescriptor.out;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.nio.channels.Channels;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.channels.WritableByteChannel;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;
import static org.apache.tomcat.jni.Shm.buffer;
import upload.UploadDownloadFileServlet;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/finalsearching1"})
public class finalsearching1 extends HttpServlet {
    private static String name,name1;
    private  static int a=0,p=0;
    int count=0;
    static URL u;
    static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024*1024;
    static HttpServletResponse response;

    private static void setContentType(HttpServletResponse response) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }
    private static void doGet1(String m1, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    }

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");


    }
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String fileName = request.getParameter("t1");
        if(fileName == null || fileName.equals("")){
            throw new ServletException("File Name can't be null or empty");
        }
        File file = new File(request.getServletContext().getRealPath("")+File.separator+fileName);
        if(!file.exists()){
            throw new ServletException("File doesn't exists on server.");
        }
        System.out.println("File location on server::"+file.getAbsolutePath());
        ServletContext ctx = getServletContext();
        InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
        String mimeType = ctx.getMimeType(file.getAbsolutePath());
        response.setContentType(mimeType != null? mimeType:"application/octet-stream");
        response.setContentLength((int) file.length());
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");

        ServletOutputStream os       = response.getOutputStream();
        byte[] bufferData = new byte[1024*1024];
        int read=0;
        while((read = fis.read(bufferData))!= -1){
            os.write(bufferData, 0, read);
        }
        os.flush();
        os.close();
        fis.close();
        System.out.println("File downloaded at client successfully");
    }
    private static void sendFile(HttpServletResponse response,  File clientFileName) throws IOException
    {
        ServletOutputStream op = null;

        setContentType(response);
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + clientFileName + "\"");

    }
    private static ServletFileUpload uploader = null;

    public static void parseAllFiles(String parentDirectory,HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, Exception  {


        PrintWriter pr=response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("text/html");


        File[] filesInDirectory = new File(parentDirectory).listFiles();

        if(filesInDirectory != null){

            for (File f : filesInDirectory){
                if(f.isDirectory()){

                    parseAllFiles(f.getAbsolutePath(),request,response);
                }
                else if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(f.getName()))
                    {

                        pr.println("File Found with path  "+f.getParentFile()+"\\"+name);

                        String m1=f.getParentFile()+"\\"+name;

                        System.out.println("File to upload: " + m1);
                        response.setContentType("text/html");

                        File file = new File(m1);
                        System.out.println();

                        String ext = "."+FilenameUtils.getExtension(m1);
                        System.out.println(ext);
                        f = File.createTempFile("tmp",ext, new File("C:\\Users\\Pankaj\\Desktop\\JADE-all-4.3.3\\WorldCupFinal\\build\\web"));
                        String f1=f.getName();

                        FileInputStream in = null;
                        FileOutputStream out = null;

                        try {
                            in = new FileInputStream(m1);


                            out = new FileOutputStream(f);

                            int c;
                            while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
                                out.write(c);
                            }
                            System.out.println(c+"  Hi");
                        }

                        finally {
                            if (in != null) {
                                in.close();
                            }
                            if (out != null) {
                                out.close();
                            }
                        }


                        pr.write("Hi..........");



                        pr.write("<br>");
                        pr.write("<a href=\"?t1="+f1+"\">Download "+name+"</a>");
                        pr.write("<br>");
                        a++;
                    }



            }
        }
    }



    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
        PrintWriter pr=response.getWriter();

        name=request.getParameter("t1");
        if(name == null || name.equals("")){
            throw new ServletException("File Name can't be null or empty");
        }



        System.out.println("name:          "+name);
        System.out.println("Starting the execution of a project  :");
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        File[] files = File.listRoots();
        for(File f : files){
            try {
                System.out.println(f.getPath());
                System.out.println("response:"+response);
                parseAllFiles(f.getPath(),request,response);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(finalsearching1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }

        if(a==0)
            pr.println("File Not Found");

        pr.println("Starting the Execution in system 2nd");
    }



    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey BalusC , Can i call another servlet after pr.println("Starting the Execution in system 2nd"); as written in my finalsearching1.java code . But here i have to fire post request by calling another servlet with query parameter as filename. I have seen your post in which you have got above 1000 likes but i am unable to assemble it with my code. Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: Anyone, Please help me for the above query